# How do I determine wall direction, with information of normal and incoming direction?

Tags: collision-detection, vector

What is formula and theorys used to determine wall direction, with only knowing the normal of the wall and the direction of the incoming object?

[This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/collision-detection-smooth-wall-sliding-no-bounce-effect) has already stated a formula, but I don't know where it came from, and I am in need of understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know the normal of the wall, then you already knows the direction of the wall. Perhaps you are unclear on what is the normal of something? See this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry).

Comment: haha youre right, im not pretty clear on normal , usage cross product and bad math haha, iknow its from perpendicular from wall ( from ai book) and some they hardcoded on on data, so i need to know theory that made em ( still studying vector math), currently i use raycast to return normal of an object, that's way i want to know direction of wall, but really want understand how it works, anyway thanks for reply :)